# Google Drive Api PHP multipart upload empty content

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api

my issue is the following. 
When using the google drive api V3 and php to upload a file to google drive, the file uploaded is empty, with a filesize of 0 bytes. All the metadata uploads no problem.

```
session_start();
$file_tmp=$_SESSION['file_tmp'];
$drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$data = file_get_contents($file_tmp);
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $file_type,
      'name' => $file_name,
      'description'=>$lolol,
      'uploadType' => 'multipart',
      'parents' => array($folderID),
      'uploadType' => 'multipart'
  ));
      $createdFile = $drive->files->create($file);
```

For anyone wondering, if I echo $file_tmp I get a path such as /private/var/tmp/phpDpmi83 .(I got this from a html form with input type file)

Originally i didn't have an UploadType and other forums said that was the issue, but I added that and still nothing.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to upload a file with `multipart/form-data` to the specific folder in Google Drive using Drive API.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for PHP.
- In your script, `$drive` can be used for uploading the file.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification point:

- In your script, please separate the metadata and file content. By this, I think that your script works.

When above point is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
session_start();
$file_tmp=$_SESSION['file_tmp'];
$drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$data = file_get_contents($file_tmp);

// I modified below script.
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'mimeType' => $file_type,
    'name' => $file_name,
    'description'=>$lolol,
    'parents' => array($folderID),
));
$file_content = array(
    'data' => $data,
    'uploadType' => 'multipart'
);
$createdFile = $drive->files->create($file, $file_content);
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that `$data` is the file content. If your `$file_tmp` cannot be used, please test using a sample file.
- In this case, the maximum file size is 5 MB. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [googleapis for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this and report the results!